# LuaTeX: \luaexec leads to 'Missing number, treated as zero.'

Tags: luatex

I can't handle Lua <--> LaTeX interaction in LuaTeX. I'm getting type errors anytime luacode is suppose to output non-string token.

For example in this case:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{luacode}

\begin{luacode*}
function params()
    tex.print(0.12)
end
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

{\adjustbox{trim={\luaexec{params()}\width} {.2\height} {0.1\width} {.15\height},clip}
      {\includegraphics[keepaspectratio,width=5cm]{pic.jpg}}}
\end{document}
```

I'll get: 'Missing number, treated as zero.'

Comment: ``\directlua{}`` instead of ``\luaexec{}`` appears to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an expansion question: `\luacode` is not expandable. Underlying the `trim` key is a TeX dimension assignment: what is given here needs to be assignable by TeX as a length, and that means any code used has to be expandable. However, if you trace the definition of `\luacode` it contains a `\begingroup` (and other stuff) which stops expansion. This non-expandable code is used to make the `\luacode` macro work, but it means that you can't structure you input in the way you want. As mentioned in a [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/155123/luatex-luaexec-leads-to-missing-number-treated-as-zero#comment354743_155123), a 'raw' `\directlua` will work here: the primitive is expandable so supplies TeX with what is required (here `0.12\textwidth`).

To explain the error itself, what happens is that TeX finds the `\begingroup` but is looking for a number. Non-expandable tokens terminate the number search but TeX hasn't got anything it can interpret as a number, so it gives an error.